# Get the first word from text and add it to input value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the **first word only** from button text and added to input after click

Check out the code here working smoothly http://jsfiddle.net/LjSYP/ and watch the output under the input I hope for

HTML

```
<div>
    <button>Feed</button>
    <button>The best</button>
    <button>Input-foo second</button>
</div>
<input id="inp" type="text" value="click a button">
```

jQuery

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#inp").val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];
    $("#inp").val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Split Function

```
 var n=text.split(" ");
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/LjSYP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#inp").val(text.split(' ')[0]);
```